# How do I add an python-only dependency of a debian package?

Tags: package-management, python, dependencies

I've got a custom made python package that I build into a deb file using debuild.  It's got a few dependencies that apt-get installs for me.  I'm trying to use a dependency that does not seem to be part of the standard ubuntu library (i.e. I can't do 'apt-get install python3-filereadbackwards' because that package doesn't exist *yet*) and I'm wondering what the best way to get that in my package.

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and what I'm trying to use is [file-read-backwards](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/file-read-backwards/1.1.2).  I'll probably just call `tail` instead, but I'd really like to be more pythonic and I'd really like to know how to do this in the future.

An alternative, I think, would just be to build my own version of file-read-backwards and maintain that. Is that the appropriate thing to do?  Is that how people become maintainers of these kinds of projects?

Comment: "I'm trying to use a dependency that is not in apt-get" explain a bit please

Comment: @anwar, sorry that was a little vague, basically, it's not in the 16.04 base packages, I only care because I've got a few hundred operating systems I'm trying to keep in sync.    I can make my own packages, but I can't use pip.

Comment: Why not just include in the package? Or you might find the file included in other packages. Have you searched packages.ubuntu.com?

Comment: @anwar,  1. I probably could do that, but I don't want to check 3rd party code into my repo, I'd rather package it separately as an artifact. 2.  I don't see the python code, I see the [perl equivalent](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libfile-readbackwards-perl) though.  so I know I'm looking in the right place.

Comment: Then you can make another package for the 3rd party lib and make it a dependency of your main package. Follow the debian policy and Ubuntu policy manual for the naming and conventional things